# using for loop to create several buttons with tkinter

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, button

I'm trying to create a calculator using tkinter.
For this purpose I used for loop to create the buttons.
The problem is that when I click each button I only get the value of the last number in the range(which is 9) in the entry box. I even tried to put the numbers in a list but the result is the same.

```
from tkinter import *
import utils

def clicked_num(num):
    display.insert(0, num)
num_list=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
for i in num_list:
    btn = Button(window, text=i, font='bold5', fg='white', bg='#008080', command=lambda: clicked_num(i))
    if i == '7':
        btn.place(x=0, y=utils.height_prc(15), width=utils.width_prc(25), height=utils.height_prc(20))
    if i == '4':
        btn.place(x=0, y=utils.height_prc(35), width=utils.width_prc(25), height=utils.height_prc(20))
    if i == '1':
        btn.place(x=0, y=utils.height_prc(55), width=utils.width_prc(25), height=utils.height_prc(20))
```

I wrote the rest just like this.

Comment: Imagine you go to click on the button and the lambda is executed when you do that click. What value would `i` have long after the button had been created? I'll see if I can find you a duplicate post that I'm sure exists someplace.